# Double Phone Number Blocking

Tags: contacts, duplicate-contacts, phone

Our priority is Name Surname and **Phone Number** while we are creating a **New Individual** Entry 
However when the same info is written, the system doesn't give a warning, which causes to create new accounts with the existed info beforehand.
to solve this problem i have examined this essay below but i haven't got the desired results.
https://civicrm.org/blog/spidersilk/understanding-civicrm-dedupe-rules

What i want is that the system shall not let me to create New Individual Entry if there is this phone number in somebody's profile already.

Could you please launch a "**Matching Rule for Individual Contacts**" to this.

*Joomla! 3.6.5 - CiviCRM 4.7.17*

Answer (score 1):

Go to Contacts > Find and Merge Duplicate Contacts > Add Rule for Individuals and create a 'Supervised' rule - eg:
[image: Name & Phone dedupe rule]

This probably only works for 'primary' phones rather than checking against all phones of a contact, but unless you have multiple phone numbers per contact, it should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

What Aidan said, but don't forget to use the Phone Number Validator extension to keep them clean and consistent!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for information. But.

I've done this before. There is no conclusion. I have the following two examples. Allows registration to be opened even though the First Name and Number match.

It may come different because I make it in Turkish on the screen. :)

[image]

**Notice that the same name and number are the same. But the new individual recording was opened.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"PHONE NUMBER VALIDATION" in order to be able to use it, it is necessary for Turkey to support the countries.

Comment: There are two extensions for validation/normalization of phone numbers you could have a look at: https://github.com/cividesk/com.cividesk.normalize https://civicrm.org/extensions/phone-number-validator